# position:fixed с overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Друзья, помогите. Есть следующий код:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
 <div style="position: fixed">
 Child div
 </div>
</div>
```

Если дочерний блок выходит за границы родительского, то overflow не работает. Как сделать при прокрутке страницы плавающий дочерний блок, с условием, что при выходе его за границы родительского он скрывался.

Comment: Для начала было бы неплохо определить эти самые "границы родительского блока" и поведение этого родительского блока относительно страницы. А потом дать определение понятию "плавающий дочерний блок" и тогда вам обязательно помогут сделать то что вы хотите :)

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду про границы родительского блока? Если вы про ширину и высоту, то это не решает проблему) Спасибо за комментарий)

Comment: Основная проблема неправильного кода в том, что тот кто его пишет не может правильно поставить вопрос о том, что он хочет получить. Поэтому давайте не будем вырывать слова из контекста, там было и про границы и про поведение, а также вопрос про "плавающий дочерний блок" (такого термина не существует и поэтому каждый увидит смысл этого понятия по своему), если ответить на все эти вопросы, то код окажется совсем другим, чем в примере вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed;` по своему действию это значение близко к `absolute`, но в отличие от него привязывается к указанной свойствами left, top, right и bottom **точке на экране** и **не меняет своего положения** при прокрутке веб-страницы.

Поэтому у вас так и происходит.

т.е другими словами блок с `position: fixed;` нельзя закрепить в другом блоке

> Whereas the position and dimensions of an element with
>   position:absolute are relative to its containing block, the position
>   and dimensions of an element with position:fixed are always relative
>   to the initial containing block. This is normally the viewport: the
>   browser window or the paper’s page box.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Fixed_positioning

Comment: Спасибо большое. Более менее стало понятно, может есть какие-нибудь хаки, которые позволяют решить вышеназванную задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Повесить fixed вместе с overflow. Больше никак.

Comment: Можете тогда объяснить, почему overflow перестает работать?

Comment: "Перестаёт"? Да оно изначально у вас не работало

Comment: Все прекрасно работает, если у дочернего стоит position: relative.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШилин У какого дочернего? Либо fixed, либо relative. Но не одновременно.